# Insert into table or create table from one command

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to save a PySpark DataFrame as a table:

```
myDf.write.saveAsTable("myDf")
```

However, if I run the code twice I get

```
u'Table `myDf` already exists.;'
```

If I save it like this:

```
myDf.write.inserInto("myDf")
```

I will get this error: `u'Table not found: myDf;'`

So how can I save a table such that regardless of how many times I run the code, I won't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you put an `if condition` to check if the table exists or not?

If not, depending on your use case, you can probably use  `registerDataFrameAsTable(df, tableName)` this registers the given DataFrame as a temporary table in the catalog, which exists only during the lifetime of the instance of SQLContext.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.registerDataFrameAsTable) for more details.
With this you should be able to run your code any number of times and not get an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
myDf.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("myDf")
```

It seems obviously an "Oh I wish I know it is so simple" scenario (happens to me all the time) but here is the [ref](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html) in case you need a bit more.

Comment: While this might work, it would be better if you explained why this works.

Comment: Added a link as the reference.